# Cassandra - how to rebind the keyspace and table? getting warning - Re-preparing already prepared query is generally an anti-pattern

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

Getting the warning:

Re-preparing already prepared query is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once.

I saw various similar questions like this [Datastax: Re-preparing already prepared query warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922538/datastax-re-preparing-already-prepared-query-warning) but they didn't address re-assigning the keyspace or table that the query uses.

I could generally re-use the query , but it will require caching it per keyspace and table, and I don't want to manage state. Alternatively I could rebind the keyspace and table before executing the query (and then no need to recreate):

// the insertion query I am using

```
def insertQuery(keyspace: String, table: String): Insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto(keyspace, table)
    .value("c1", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
    .value("c2")
    .value(...)
    .value("c_n")
```

Would need something like this:

```
QueryBuilder.insertInto(keyspace = ???BIND MARKER????, table = ???BIND MARKER???)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind keyspace & table names...

If you don't want to cache prepared queries, then you really don't need to use them - just generate `SimpleStatement` instead - it will be more effective because right now if you prepare on every request, you're doing 2 network roundtrips - one for preparing query, and another for its execution.

But I would recommend to prepare all necessary queries at startup/first connection, because they could bring quite significant performance improvement (if you care, of course).

Comment: Use some cache inside your program to keep already prepared statements...