# How does "putIfAbsent" works in CHM?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, guava, concurrenthashmap

I am working with Cassandra and using Datastax Java driver. I am trying to reuse prepared statements by caching it.

```
  private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, PreparedStatement> holder = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    Session session = TestUtils.getInstance().getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps = holder.get(cql);
    // no statement is cached, create one and cache it now.
    if (ps == null) {
      holder.putIfAbsent(cql, session.prepare(cql));
    }
    return ps.bind();
  }
```

[Prepared Statement](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/da72105c2fcef8f0865047815df146cfbb2354e6/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/PreparedStatement.java) and [BoundStatement](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/da72105c2fcef8f0865047815df146cfbb2354e6/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.java) of datastax java driver.

This `getStatement` method will be called by multiple threads so I have to make sure it is thread safe. I am working with Java 7.

What will `putIfAbsent` do here if we get two same cql prepared statements? Is my code thread safe and there is no race condition?

**Update:-**

```
  public BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    Session session = TestUtils.getInstance().getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps = holder.get(cql);
    // no statement is cached, create one and cache it now.
    if (ps == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        ps = holder.get(cql);
        if (ps == null) {
          ps = session.prepare(cql);
          holder.put(cql, ps);
        }
      }
    }
    return ps.bind();
  }
```

Comment: How about now? Does it look right?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a race condition which can result in `session.prepare(cql)` being called twice (or more) for any `cql` parameter. The `putIfAbsent` doesn't really offer any advantage over a normal `put` in this case.

If you were on Java 8, you could write this efficiently without creating duplicates with

```
PreparedStatement ps = holder.computeIfAbsent(cql, key -> session.prepare(key));
```

Comment: If anyone has a great usecase for `putIfAbsent`, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: I am still on Java 7. What can I do to avoid this issue with Java 7?

Comment: @david To be honest I don't have a very elegant solution for Java 7. You'd need to manually lock the `get / check for null / put` part.

Comment: I see, can you provide an example for that if possible. That will help me to understand how to lock get and put in a atomic way.

Comment: @david Well, with a `Lock` for example, or isolate the operations in a `synchronized` method. Whatever to make it atomic.

Comment: It’s hard to say what the correct solution is, when there is so little context. If this method is called by different threads with the same string, it might return the same statement. So the first question is, whether this is correct, i.e. whether the statement works when being executed by different threads at the same time. Compared to that, the potential impact of having two different statement instances for the same string, is ridiculously low. You still can enforce the use of the same statement instance by using the result of `putIfAbsent`, if non-`null`.

Comment: `putIfAbsent` is useful, whenever it is acceptable to temporarily calculate the same value/ create an equivalent instance, as long as the final result will be the canonical value stored in the map or that potential duplicate calculation has a minor performance impact as concurrent invocations with the same key rarely happen.

Comment: @Holger Yeah. Less obvious than with `computeIfAbsent` though.

Comment: Of course, `computeIfAbsent` is much easier to use, but `putIfAbsent` exists since Java 5, created at a time when the necessary features didn’t exist to allow `computeIfAbsent`, no functional interfaces nor no lambda expressions and no support for bucket locking within the CHM implementation…

Answer (score 1):

You indeed do have a race condition, but your `putIfAbsent` is still probably slightly better than pure `put`, as it keeps the old statement, so there are never two instances in real use. The advantage is tiny as it manifests only in case of a race condition.

It looks like a version of a [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). Just put a synchronized block around the initialization a recheck if it's really needed.

I'm rather sceptical about caching the `PreparedStatement` as it's mutable. You may need multiple instances for the same `cql`. This is doable, too, but you'd need to acquire and release them properly.

Comment: My idea of caching the prepared statement came from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915840/re-using-preparedstatement-when-using-datastax-cassandra-driver) otherwise it will keep giving warning every time.

Comment: I have updated the question with synchronized block. That's what you meant?

Comment: @david Yes, the synchronized block looks fine. Concerning the mutability, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22917891/581205) looks good (I know nothing about Cassandra). Btw., your original race condition is acceptable as all you risk is getting the efficiency warning.